# Changing scroll position from another view not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working on a project where I need to reset a TabView's root view controllers (NavigationViews with Lists inside) when the TabViews selected item changes. This is pretty simple in UIKit, however in SwiftUI it doesn't seem that easy.

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<AppState, Never>()
    
    @Published var theScrollPosition: Int64? {
        didSet {
            print("Did set scroll position")
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    @Published var selectedTab: Tabs
    {
        didSet {
            print("Tab switched, switching back to root view")
            selectedItemID = nil
            selectedRow = nil
            theScrollPosition = -1
          
        }
    }
    
    @Published var selectedItemID: Int64? {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    @Published var selectedRow: Int64? {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var state: AppState
  var body: some View {
    TabView {
      View1().id(Tabs.Tab1)
      View2().id(Tabs.Tab2)
      View3().id(Tabs.Tab3)
    }
 }
}

struct View1: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var state: AppState
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ListViewModel()
  var body: some View {
  ScrollViewReader { proxy in
  List(viewModel.items) { item in
    Section {
      NavigationLink(destination:ListItemDetailView(item), tag: item.id, selection: state.selectedItemID) {
        ListItemView(item)
      }
    }

  }.onChange(of: self.state.selectedItemID) { newValue in
print("Scrolling to top")
  proxy.scrollTo(0)
  }
}

}
```

There may be some typos in the code as this is not the actual production code however the flow is this:

Selection state of TabView and NavigationLink are stored in a global EnvironmentObject. When the TabView selection changes, View1 should scroll back up to the top.

However, the onChange method is never called.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. But I can tell you that your code is mixing really old code (SwiftUI 1.0 beta) and current methods, you are likely overriding something not knowing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Next time, provide something runnable or at least a start...

But here is a example where view 1 will always scroll to the top, you are missing something like onAppear()

And you don't need to have AppState.theScrollPosition as a published, instead change to the right tab and have that view read the position or tag in the model.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var view: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Text("TOP").id("topID")
                    Divider()
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height:1000)
                    Text("BOTTOM").id("bottomID")
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                proxy.scrollTo("topID")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    var view2: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View 2")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            view.tag(0)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("View 1")
                }
            view2.tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("View 2")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for some reason I was totally missing onAppear.

Comment: I think you meant to comment on the other answer, not create a new answer for your question